# Angular 2 - Getter function to split array into chunks of 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, typescript, getter

Working on an application and the framework I am using has rows and I would like to iterate over an array of devices and input them into rows, 3 devices per row.

I was pointed in the direction of using a getter function to split the array, I am just not sure how to implmenet this in my component.ts file.

Below is the function I am attempting to implement

```
get deviceRows() {
    let arrRows = [];
    let deviceTriple = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.devices.length; i++) {
        deviceTriple.push(this.devices[i - 1]);
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            arrRows.push(triple);
            deviceTriple= [];
        }
    }
    return arrRows;
}
```

And this is the file I would like to implement this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DeviceService } from '../../services/device.service';
import { Device } from '../../../Device';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'devices',
  templateUrl: 'devices.component.html'
})
export class DevicesComponent {
  devices: Device[];
  name: string;

  constructor(private deviceService:DeviceService) {
    this.deviceService.getDevices()
      .subscribe(devices => {
        this.devices = devices;
      });
  }
  addDevice(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newDevice = {
      name: this.name,
      onStatus: false
    }
    this.deviceService.addDevice(newDevice)
      .subscribe(device => {
        this.devices.push(device);
        this.name = '';
      });
  }
  deleteDevice(id) {
    var devices = this.devices;

    this.deviceService.deleteDevice(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(data.n == 1){
          for(var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            if(devices[i]._id == id){
              devices.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }
        }
      });
  }
  toggleDevice(device){
    var updatedStatus = {
      _id: device._id,
      name: device.name,
      onStatus: !device.onStatus
    };

    this.deviceService.toggleDevice(updatedStatus)
      .subscribe(data => {
        device.onStatus = !device.onStatus
        updatedStatus = {};
      });
  }
}
```

Inside the view I would like to use something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let DeviceTriple of deviceRows">
    <div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center" uk-grid>
        <div *ngFor="let device of DeviceTriple">
            <h2 class="uk-h2">{{ device.name }}</h2>
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" (click)="toggleDevice(device)"  [disabled]="device.onStatus">On</button>
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-danger" (click)="toggleDevice(device)" [disabled]="!device.onStatus">Off</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is how it I currently added devices to the DOM.

```
<div class="uk-child-width-expand@s uk-text-center uk-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let device of devices">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-transform-origin-bottom-right uk-animation-scale-up">
            <h2 class="uk-h2">
                <a href="api/device/{{device._id}}">
                    {{ device.name }} 
                </a>
            </h2>
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" (click)="toggleDevice(device)"  [disabled]="device.onStatus">On</button>
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-danger" (click)="toggleDevice(device)" [disabled]="!device.onStatus">Off</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am new to Angular and I am not sure this is the most effient way of doing this, I have seen suggestions about using a custom pipe to do this, but I am lost when looking at examples of implementing this.

Any guidance would be greatly received. If I insert the function anywhere outside of the **export class DevicesComponent** I get the error *'get is not defined'*. If I place it after **name: string;** I get the error *cannot get .length of undefined.*